# Save MKPointAnnotation to Firestore

Tags: objective-c, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints, mkpointannotation

I have [mkmapview annotations] which is array of MKPointAnnotation

I am trying to save ti to FireStore as array but is not accepted the MKPointAnnotation object

then I try to convert MKPointAnnotation to FIRGeoPoint but no luck

```
for (MKPointAnnotation *point in annotationsArray) {
        FIRGeoPoint *FirAnnotations;
        FirAnnotations = [FirAnnotations initWithLatitude:point.coordinate.latitude longitude:point.coordinate.longitude];
        NSLog(@"FirAnnotations: %@",FirAnnotations);
    }
```

annotationsArray is [mkmapview annotations]

**always get null**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'am attempting to use the FirAnnotations pointer to call init but it's nil and i should be using the FIRGeoPoint there.

```
for (MKPointAnnotation *point in annotationsArray) {
        FIRGeoPoint *FirAnnotations;
        FirAnnotations = [[FIRGeoPoint alloc] initWithLatitude:point.coordinate.latitude                                                longitude:point.coordinate.longitude];
        NSLog(@"annotations: %@",annotations);
}
```